# Flutter assertion failed Error in ListView Builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm Trying learn flutter and i'm a beginner.I'm trying to list down my shopping cart items in flutter application. Below is my shopping cart code and widget.but i'm getting below error when i tried to access the cart. can someone help me to resolve this issue.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:distribution/Providers/ShoppingCartProvider.dart';
import 'package:distribution/models/ShoppingCart/CartItem.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../widgets/ShoppingCart/ShoppingCartItem.dart';

class ShoppingCartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/shoppingcart';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<ShoppingCartProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Your Cart'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const Text('Total', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Chip(
                          label: Text(
                            '\$${cart.totalAmount}',
                          ),
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          child: Text('ORDER NOW'),
                          onPressed: () {},
                         
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: cart.items.length,
                            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ShoppingCartItem(
                              cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                              cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
                              cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
                              cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                              cart.items.values.toList()[i].title,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ))),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

this is the part giving me problem

```
                  Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: cart.items.length,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ShoppingCartItem(
                          cart.items.values.toList()[i].id,
                          cart.items.keys.toList()[i],
                          cart.items.values.toList()[i].price,
                          cart.items.values.toList()[i].quantity,
                          cart.items.values.toList()[i].title,
                        ),
                      ),
```

my shopping cart widget code

```
import 'package:distribution/Providers/ShoppingCartProvider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class ShoppingCartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String productId;
  final double price;
  final int quantity;
  final String title;

   ShoppingCartItem(
    this.id,
    this.productId,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.title,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding:const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: Padding(
                padding:const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text('\$$price'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(title),
            subtitle: Text('Total: '),
            trailing: Text('x'),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Shopping cart provider

```
import 'package:distribution/models/ShoppingCart/CartItem.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class ShoppingCartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};

  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  void addItem(
    String productID,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productID)) {
      _items.update(
          productID,
          (existingitem) => CartItem(
                id: existingitem.id,
                title: existingitem.title,
                quantity: existingitem.quantity + 1,
                price: existingitem.price,
              ));
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
          productID,
          () => CartItem(
                id: DateTime.now().toString(),
                title: title,
                price: price,
                quantity: 1,
              ));
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items == null ? 0 :_items.length;
  }

  double get totalAmount {
    var total = 0.0;
    _items.forEach((key, cartitem) { 
      total += cartitem.price * cartitem.quantity ;
    });
    return total;
  }

  void removeItem(String productId) {
    _items.remove(productId);
    notifyListeners();
  }
  
}
```

shopping cart model

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final int quantity;
  final double price;

  CartItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.quantity,
    @required this.price

  });
}
```

Error I'm Getting

```
Error: Assertion failed: file:///Users/liyanaarachchi/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1927:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#60a6a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT"
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:5386:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:5308:15)
    at proxy_box.RenderPointerListener.new.get size [as size] (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4406:42)
    at proxy_box.RenderPointerListener.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:545:26)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8537:44
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at custom_layout.RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.new.defaultHitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8533:30)
    at custom_layout.RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart.lib.js:304:19)
    at custom_layout.RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at material._RenderInkFeatures.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at material._RenderInkFeatures.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderPhysicalModel.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderPhysicalModel.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderPhysicalModel.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:2343:20)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderIgnorePointer.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderIgnorePointer.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderIgnorePointer.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3794:59)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8537:44
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at stack.RenderStack.new.defaultHitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8533:30)
    at stack.RenderStack.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart.lib.js:683:19)
    at stack.RenderStack.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderDecoratedBox.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderDecoratedBox.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3327:24
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3324:21)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3317:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3327:24
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3324:21)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3317:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at routes._RenderFocusTrap.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at routes._RenderFocusTrap.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart.lib.js:19335:36)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderOffstage.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderOffstage.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderOffstage.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3906:59)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart.lib.js:29639:42
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at overlay$._RenderTheatre.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart.lib.js:29635:28)
    at overlay$._RenderTheatre.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderAbsorbPointer.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderAbsorbPointer.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderAbsorbPointer.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3989:79)
    at proxy_box.RenderPointerListener.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderPointerListener.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:546:36)
    at custom_paint.RenderCustomPaint.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at custom_paint.RenderCustomPaint.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart.lib.js:343:20)
    at custom_paint.RenderCustomPaint.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at view.RenderView.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4953:58)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:5834:23)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerEventImmediately] (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:333:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.handlePointerEvent (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:325:43)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_flushPointerEventQueue] (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:314:14)
    at binding$5.WidgetsFlutterBinding.new.[_handlePointerDataPacket] (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart.lib.js:304:65)
    at Object.invoke1 (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:202716:7)
    at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.invokeOnPointerDataPacket (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:182673:15)
    at _engine.PointerBinding.__.[_onPointerData] (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:183574:49)
    at http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:184046:26
    at http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:184011:16
    at loggedHandler (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:183684:11)
Error: Assertion failed: file:///Users/liyanaarachchi/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1927:12
hasSize
"RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#60a6a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT"
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:5386:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:64556/dart_sdk.js:5308:15)
    at proxy_box.RenderPointerListener.new.get size [as size] (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4406:42)
    at proxy_box.RenderPointerListener.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:545:26)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8537:44
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at custom_layout.RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.new.defaultHitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8533:30)
    at custom_layout.RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart.lib.js:304:19)
    at custom_layout.RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at material._RenderInkFeatures.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at material._RenderInkFeatures.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderPhysicalModel.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderPhysicalModel.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderPhysicalModel.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:2343:20)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderIgnorePointer.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderIgnorePointer.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderIgnorePointer.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3794:59)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8537:44
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at stack.RenderStack.new.defaultHitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8533:30)
    at stack.RenderStack.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart.lib.js:683:19)
    at stack.RenderStack.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderDecoratedBox.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderDecoratedBox.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3327:24
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3324:21)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3317:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3327:24
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3324:21)
    at proxy_box.RenderFractionalTranslation.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3317:19)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderRepaintBoundary.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at routes._RenderFocusTrap.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at routes._RenderFocusTrap.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart.lib.js:19335:36)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderOffstage.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderOffstage.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at proxy_box.RenderOffstage.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:3906:59)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart.lib.js:448:56)
    at proxy_box.RenderSemanticsAnnotations.new.hitTest (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:4651:28)
    at http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart.lib.js:29639:42
    at box.BoxHitTestResult.wrap.addWithPaintOffset (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart.lib.js:8267:19)
    at overlay$._RenderTheatre.new.hitTestChildren (http://localhost:64556/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart.lib.js:29635:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should fix it just add `shrinkWrap: true` to ListView

Comment: Thanks it worked..!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).